# Handle keydown event of ANY <textarea> on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to handle the case where someone presses ENTER on any `<textarea>` on my page.  Not all of the `<textarea>`'s are on the page when it loads (they can be added dynamically through user events), so I don't know each `<textarea>` id at page load (and therefore can't use jQuery to listen to each event by id).  I also tried to use the JS `onkeydown` event, but I haven't been able to find a way to detect which key caused the `onkeydown` event to fire.

So, is there a way to handle all `<textarea>` keydown's on my page, along with which key caused the event, or is there an elegant solution I seem to be missing?  Some global event?

Comment: ". I also tried to use the JS onkeydown event, but I haven't been able to find a way to detect which key caused the onkeydown event to fire" Really ??

Comment: @MattW Please ensure you do <b>some</b> research before posting questions here. A [Google search for "keydown enter jquery"](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=keydown+enter+jquery) and clicking on [the first link](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) takes you to a page which has information on everything you asked for as well as a live demo to check the .which values for any key!!

Comment: I did!  I was not understanding how to do it for my specific situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delegate`. You can specify the `body` or any `container` which will hold all these dynamic textareas.

```
$("body").delegate("textarea", "keydown",function(e){
  // code logic goes here
  if(e.which == 13){
     //Enter key down    
  }
});
```

Comment: I used this one, but added the event (as mentioned in sje397's post).  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("textarea").live("keydown",function(){
  // process
})
```

Or you can use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

What this does is apply the listener to all textareas on execution and in the future of that instance.  So if any textareas are added by the DOM, it will bind that keypress to them also.

Answer (score 2):

`event.which` tells you which key.

```
$('textarea').live("keydown", function(e) {
    // e.which is which key, e.g. 13 == enter
});
```

Docs on [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
Docs on [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JQuery and then as the textarea's are added "dynamically" add the listener / handler .... there are plenty of examples around for handling the onKeyPress event

Comment: Given the question, I imagine that your answer would be much improved if you added/explained how that might be done.